# Order of normalizer Sylow 5-subgroup in Suzuki group

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

It known the Suzuki group $Sz(q)$, where $q=2^{2n+1}$ is of order $q^2(q^{2}+1)(q-1)$. By $2^{2}$ $=-1$ mod $5$, then $2^{2n}$ $=(-1)^{n}$ mod $5$. So $q=2^{2n+1}$ $=2(-1)^{n}$ mod $5$ and so $q^{2}+1=0$ mod $5$. Therefore $5$ always divide order of $Sz(q)$.

My question is: If $P$ is a Sylow $5$-subgroup of the group $Sz(q)$, then order of normalizer of $P$ in $Sz(q)$? Thanks.

Comment: I'm reluctant to upvote the question, since it should start with a search of the available literature on Suzuki groups (which you seem to know something about).    As Nick points out, the original two-part paper by Michio Suzuki (Ann. of Math. 1962, 1964) already contains lots of relevant detail.   Theorem 9 occurs in Part I.  These papers are available online via JSTOR if you have access.  

Comment: Just in case someone comes across this question in the future, I record the normalizer $N$ of a Sylow $s$-subgroup of $G=Sz(q)$ for each prime $s$ dividing $\#G$.  Note that $\#G=q^2(q-1)(q+r+1)(q-r+1)$ where $r^2=2q$.  If $s=2$ then $N$ is a Frobenius group of order $q^2(q-1)$.  If $s\mid (q-1)$ then $N$ is dihedral of order $2(q-1)$.  If $s\mid (q+r+1)$ then $N=C_{q+r+1}\rtimes C_4$.  If $s\mid (q-r+1)$ then $N=C_{q-r+1}\rtimes C_4$.  All of this (and much much more) is immediate from Suzuki's 1962 paper.

Answer (score 10):

Go to Suzuki's original paper *On a class of doubly transitive groups*. Theorem 9 of that paper lists all of the subgroups of $G=Sz(q)$. In particular, setting $q=2^{2a+1}$ and $r=2^{a+1}$, there is a maximal subgroup $M$ of order $4(q-r+1)$. Now $M$ has a cyclic normal subgroup $C$ of order $q-r+1$ which contains $P$, a Sylow $5$-subgroups of $G$. Since a subgroup of a cyclic group is characteristic, this implies that $M$ normalizes $P$. Since $M$ is maximal we conclude that $M=N_G(P)$.

Comment: Minor correction: this answer implicitly assumes that $q-r+1$ is divisible by $5$, i.e., that $a$ is congruent to $1$ or $2$ mod $4$.  If $a$ is congruent to $0$ or $3$ mod $4$ then $N_G(P)$ has order $4(q+r+1)$, by the same argument as what you wrote.